# Module level setup and teardown with nose2

Tags: python, installation, nose

How does one indicate module-level setup and teardown methods with nose2?  It doesn't seem to be the same as with nose and I can't find documentation.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The introduced `layers` plugin to organize fixtures and per-module setup. https://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/layers.html